# Options for select using map and a custom option

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line on my code working fine:

```
<%= select_tag "group_id", options_for_select(@monitor_groups.map{|mg|[mg.name, mg.id] }) %>
```

Besides the monitor_group id and name options I need an additional option for "All" using id 0, but I can't add this on monitor_group, so I need to add this on my options for select.

Something like:

```
<%= select_tag "group_id", options_for_select(@monitor_groups.map{|mg|[mg.name, mg.id] }, ["All", 0]) %>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: try `<%= select_tag "group_id", options_for_select(@monitor_groups.map{|mg|[mg.name, mg.id] }.push(["All", 0])) %>`

Comment: YESSS! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `["All", 0]` with your options.

Try like this:

```
<%= select_tag "group_id", options_for_select(@monitor_groups.map{|mg|[mg.name, mg.id] } + ["All", 0]) %>
```

Or

```
<%= select_tag "group_id", options_for_select(@monitor_groups.map{|mg|[mg.name, mg.id] }.push(["All", 0])) %>
```

Explanation:

```
@monitor_groups.map{|mg|[mg.name, mg.id] }
```

will return an array then add `["All", 0]`  with your returned array.